# How to get rid of this useless GWT compiler warning?

Tags: gwt

There is an option in GWT to obfuscate enum names:

```
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.enum.obfuscate.names" value="true" />
```

When I use this option, my compiles produce a warning:

```
[WARN] Call to Enum method name when enum obfuscation is enabled:
com/google/gwt/dom/client/DataTransfer.java:127
```

Looking at the `DataTransfer` source code, I can see that it has an enum `DropEffect` and the enum names are used in one of the methods (`setDropEffect`).

I'm using modern JsInterop-oriented GWT, so I'm not using this `DataTransfer` class (or anything in `gwt-user.jar`). It's annoying to have a useless warning. Is there an easy way to get rid of it?

I know how to exclude files in my own source folders.

Is it possible to exclude source folders from `gwt-user`? (Other than by physically deleting files from the jar!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug - unfortunate too that the compiler doesn't remove this class. This should be easy to fix with a patch to GWT, adding a field to DropEffect for the name, since it must never be removed even when that compiler flag is enabled.

> Is it possible to exclude source folders from gwt-user? (Other than by physically deleting files from the jar!)

What you must do is exclude the `.gwt.xml` file itself, by not inheriting it at all, even transitively. So, for example, if you do avoid all JSNI including Widget types in the `User` module, your `.gwt.xml` shouldn't reference the `Dom` module, or `User`, or anything else which references `Dom`. But once a module has been inherited, there is no way to "uninherit" it. And once a module is inherited, its sources are added, and cannot be un-added.

Comment: Right, it's a transitive dependency. I'm not using any Widgets, but I'm depending on modules for GSS - `com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N` and `com.google.gwt.resources.Resources`. The latter depends on `com.google.gwt.dom.DOM` and that's where `DataTransfer` lives. Do you know if these GSS modules have been rewritten for JsInterop, or if there's a better alternative to them?

Comment: Actually, I'll ask that as a separate question.

Comment: They have, though I don't think this bug was fixed. They also haven't been released to maven central yet.

Comment: Awesome! I can't wait for GWT 3 to come out. I hope it happens in my lifetime :)

Comment: With apologies to William Gibson, J2cl is here, its just not evenly distributed. The j2cl-maven-plugin that I'm working on (on leave right now, will return soon) functions in the same way as the "ltgt" gwt-maven-plugin, and has no use for a .gwt.xml file, but transpiles any sources you give it on your dependency tree.